# Remember each of the checkbox selections in a session

Tags: php, html, session, checkbox

Ive got a 3 part form and i want to store the users selections in a session so if they need to go back and change a selection they can.

The form consists of radio buttons and checkboxes. I have it working for the radio buttons they are stored in a session so it always remembers.

I can't think how to go it working on the checkboxes as they are stored in an array.

This is my form:

[image]

So when they select jam and Flora, i get an array like this

```
Array ( [0] => Jam [1] => Flora )
```

This is my checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $course_menuname."extras[]"; ?>" <?php if($_SESSION[''.$course_menuname.''] == $extraitems) { echo "checked"; } ?> value="<?php echo $extraitems; ?>">
```

So i need a session to store each of the values they selected then if its one they selected put a check on the checkbox.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Whats in $_SESSION[$course_menuname] and in $extraitems?

Comment: $_SESSION[$course_menuname] has the course like "breakfast_cereal" and "breakfast_toast" and "breakfast_toastextras" and $extraitems has each of the extras in it, such as "jam" "butter" and "flora" that line is what im using for the radio buttons, it was just an example, im not sure how to approach it for multiple selections

Comment: try `in_array` http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

i was also suffering from same problem, below solution worked fine for me, make appropriate changes before use,

```
<input type='checkbox' name='list[0]' id='product' value='Product'></input>
<input type='checkbox' name='list[1]' id='product' value='Product'></input>
```

Here I am setting my variable with the POST of the checkboxes.

```
$checkboxes = $_POST['list'];
$_SESSION['list'] = $checkboxes;
```

And use foreach so we know that in `$_SESSION['list']` we have only checked ones!

```
 foreach ($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $value)
    {

             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="list['$key']" value="'.$value.'" checked="checked >';           
    }
```